# While doing data normalization, I always get ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to normalize my CSV data by doing decimal scaling using this code

```
def decimal_scaling(data):
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
    max_row = data.max(axis=0)
    c = np.array([len(str(int(number))) for number in np.abs(max_row)])
    return data/(10**c)

X = decimal_scaling(
            glcm_df[['dissimilarity_0', 'dissimilarity_45', 'dissimilarity_90', 'dissimilarity_135', 
                     'correlation_0', 'correlation_45', 'correlation_90', 'correlation_135', 
                     'homogeneity_0', 'homogeneity_45', 'homogeneity_90', 'homogeneity_135', 
                     'contrast_0', 'contrast_45', 'contrast_90', 'contrast_135', 
                     'ASM_0', 'ASM_45', 'ASM_90', 'ASM_135',
                     'energy_0', 'energy_45', 'energy_90', 'energy_135']].values)
```

But, everytime I run it, I always get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-5b1233475b8c> in <module>
     22                      'contrast_0', 'contrast_45', 'contrast_90', 'contrast_135',
     23                      'ASM_0', 'ASM_45', 'ASM_90', 'ASM_135',
---> 24                      'energy_0', 'energy_45', 'energy_90', 'energy_135']].values)

<ipython-input-21-5b1233475b8c> in decimal_scaling(data)
     13     data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
     14     max_row = data.max(axis=0)
---> 15     c = np.array([len(str(int(number))) for number in np.abs(max_row)])
     16     return data/(10**c)
     17 

<ipython-input-21-5b1233475b8c> in <listcomp>(.0)
     13     data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
     14     max_row = data.max(axis=0)
---> 15     c = np.array([len(str(int(number))) for number in np.abs(max_row)])
     16     return data/(10**c)
     17 

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I'm not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy `floats` allow `NaN` values but `int`s don't.  So the NaN propagates through your float calculations until it hits the `int` conversion.

That is, you are reading the `data` which results in some NaN values, then `max` returns a NaN for these rows, and the same for `abs` also return NaN, then `int()` complains.

Try:

```
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32) # from your code
print(np.argwhere(np.isnan(data)))
```

to find where your NaN values are.

Comment: Where exactly should I run `np.argwhere(np.isnan(data))`? Tried writing it in each line in the `decimal_scaling` function but it doesn't return or print out anything.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html), `argwhere` returns a list of indices. That's how you can know which are NaNs.

Comment: @arahpanah: put it in right after you read the data, or anywhere, but you have to print out the results to see where the nans are. I've edited my code to show that.

Comment: @tom10 Thanks! Found it! It works now. Turns out there are 7 rows of incomplete data in the bottom of the dataset.